# Fetching data from three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables **category**, **brand**, **product**.
Category table -

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_UID  | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| date          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time          | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_delete     | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Brand  table -

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| brand_UID  | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| fk_id      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time       | time         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_delete  | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Products -

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_UID    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| brand_UID       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_UID     | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| keyword         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| photo           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| photo_thumbnail | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date            | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time            | time         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_delete       | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| visible         | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In HTML page there is a search type input in which user will type atleast three characters to get the serach result from DB.
**How will be search technique -**
I want to search for products and grab all their data.
The search string will be find by product_name or keywords from product table.
If the search string doesn't found in product table then the search string may be find by `category_name` or `brand_name` from category table or brand table respectively. Now If we get our search then the **category_UID** must be present in product table. (It means we will get our search only when that category UID stored in product table)
**I want to get the output  as -**
If search success, we must get all the column data from product table including two more columns `category_name`, `brand_name` from category table and brand table respectively.
**Note :**
only one attribute `category_UID` is common in all three tables.
So How can I get the search for product ?
Is this can be solved by **JOIN** or **UNION** technique else I  have to use procedural way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table, category_UID and product_UID are the foreign keys references, then the following query will work.

```
select  p.id as id,p.category_UID as category_UID,p.brand_UID as brand_UID,
        p.product_name as product_name,p.product_UID as product_UID,p.keyword as keyword,
        p.photo as photo,p.photo_thumbnail as photo_thumbnail,p.date as date,p.time as time,
        p.is_delete as is_delete,p.visible as visible,c.category_name as category_name, b.brand_name as brand_name
        FROM product as p 
        JOIN Brand as b ON p.brand_UID = b.brand_UID
        JOIN category as c ON p.category_UID = c.category_UID 
        where p.product_name like '%<search_str>%' OR
        p.keyword like '%<search_str>%' OR
        b.brand_name like '%<search_str>%' OR
        c.category_name like '%<search_str>%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but an error occured, _Unknown column 'b.category_UID' in 'on clause'_

Comment: updated query statement again. please execute updated query

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing that What if we have 4 times of dozen arrtributes in product table then we have to write one by one attributes for creating sql query, This is painful.

Comment: We can specify `*` instead of column names, But in this result, the query will return all data from all joined tables(in this case all three tables). Also, it has a chance of Column ambiguity

Comment: I am using * to short the sql query, But the duplicated columns printed, Is there any solution to remove duplicated column by still using `*` ? else I have to remove duplicate columns by using php.

Comment: Better choice is use required column name instead of *, this will help MySQL queries performance. You can remove those duplicate key values using php. But it's a bad practice.

Comment: The best practice is to specify the column names that you want from the query, this will improve performance. If you specify * that will return all columns of all those columns.